# Javascript convert a list of string coords into two float lists of Lat/Lng coords?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list

This is what i currently have:

```
var coords1 = ["52.535614,-7.285257", "52.571321,-1.585436", "53.535614,-2.285257"];
```

This is my aim:

```
lat1 = [52.535614, 52.571321, 53.535614]
lng1 = [-7.285257, -1.585436, -2.285257]
```

I know how to do it individually:

```
a = coords1[0]
b = a.split(',');
c = b[0];
d = b[1];

e = Number(c);
f = Number(d);
>> 52.535614
>> -7.285257
```

I could append these to individual lists, but i'm assuming this isn't a very efficient way, and was wondering how to do this with an almost infinite coords list.

Comment: `const parts = coords1.map(s => s.split(",").map(Number));` then `const lat1 = parts.map(a => a[0])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could split and map numbers and push to the related arrays.

```js
var coords = ["52.535614,-7.285257", "52.571321,-1.585436", "53.535614,-2.285257"],
    lat = [],
    lng = [];

coords.forEach(s => s
    .split(',')
    .map(Number)
    .forEach((v, i) => [lat, lng][i].push(v))
);

console.log(lat);
console.log(lng);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with only one loop. For this way you need use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Rest_parameters) and [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```js
const coords1 = ["52.535614,-7.285257", "52.571321,-1.585436", "53.535614,-2.285257"];

const [firstCoord, secondCoord] = coords1.reduce((acc, rec) => {  // use rest parametr
  const comma = rec.indexOf(',') // find index of comma
  return [ 
  ...acc, // copy accamulator of reduce
    acc[0].push(rec.slice(0, comma)), // get first part of string
    acc[1].push(rec.slice(comma + 1, rec.length)) // get second part of string
  ]
}, [[], []]) // special initial value

console.log(firstCoord)
console.log(secondCoord)
```